# How to rename a file without closing all of it's open file handles?

Tags: windows, winapi, file-io, createfile

I create `GENERIC_READ` file handle with `createFile`. 
This is my instruction :

```
   hfile :=  CreateFileA(aFileName,  
                         GENERIC_READ,  
                         FILE_SHARE_READ or 
                           FILE_SHARE_WRITE,  
                         nil,  
                         OPEN_EXISTING,  
                         FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL or 
                           FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN or 
                             FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
                         0);
```

Now the problem is that when to process will read the file via `hfile` sometime another process will need to "swap" the file, and to do this will need to **rename it**

this is how I do it :

```
MoveFileA(aFileName, aNewFileName);
```

But I have an error when I do this when their is still some file handle open. Is their any way to rename a file without first closing all it's GENERIC_READ file handle?

Comment: `:=` - What are you programming in again?

Comment: @StoryTeller Delphi and C++ (here the code sample is from delphi)

Comment: That appears to be a Delphi assignment operator.

Comment: Yeah, I wised up to it when reading further and seeing `nil`. I'm ambivalent about the C++ tag in your question then. It's not C++ specific is it? Not even Delphi specific, but at least the code is Delphi.

Comment: You keep asking the same question over and over again, pertaining to solving issues with your dubious design. Fix your design. Besides, there is **no** reason to use the ANSI version of API calls. Especially with file names, they **will** fail at some point.

Comment: rename(inside same volume) worked without any problems on open file

Comment: @IInspectable : "You keep asking the same question over and over again" => what you mean ? where i ask the same question ??

Comment: @loki - you question have no sense in such form. `MoveFileA` perfect worked on open file too. you even not past what error you get - what you want listen based on this info ?

Comment: @RbMm : seam you are right, adding FILE_SHARE_DELETE did the trick !

Comment: @RbMm i confirm FILE_SHARE_DELETE is the good answer, without it i have: process can't rename the file because it's used by another process

Comment: `MoveFile` opens a handle via `NtOpenFile` and does the rename via `NtSetInformationFile`. Renaming a file is essentially a delete from its current directory, so it requires delete access, which is a shared access right (see [`IoCheckShareAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-iocheckshareaccess)). There's a single `SHARE_ACCESS` record in the file system's File/Stream Control Block for the file, which gets used by all kernel File objects that reference the FCB/SCB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously the preferred choice is to ensure that every time the file is opened, the `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` flag is passed.

If you can't do that (e.g., some other process over which you have no control may open it) the remaining alternative is to use `MoveFileEx` with the `MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT` flag. As you'd guess from the name, this waits until the next time the computer is restarted, and renames it then. This is particularly useful for files that are used by something like a service that opens them as soon as the service starts, and keeps them open until the system is shut down.

This does have some limitations of its own though. For one example, you can't use it to rename a file via a network share. The renaming is done *fairly* early in the boot process, before persistent network shares are re-connected.

Answer (score 0):

Open another `HANDLE` to the file and then use [`SetFileInformationByHandle()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365539.aspx), setting the `FileInformationClass` parameter to `FileRenameInfo`, and the `lpFileInformation` parameter to a pointer to a [`FILE_RENAME_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364398.aspx) struct.

Comment: `MoveFile[Ex]` essentially works the same way, except it directly uses NTAPI `NtOpenFile` and `NtSetInformationFile` instead of WINAPI `CreateFile` and `SetFileInformationByHandle`. Importantly, `MoveFile` also opens a reparse point directly. It re-opens with reparsing only if the reparse point is not a mount point (junction) or symlink.

Answer (score -1):

just add FILE_SHARE_DELETE to do the job

Comment: Not my downvote, but maybe it would help if you flesh out the answer with context to show that you actually understand how this works. It assumes cooperation by all users that require data access (i.e. execute, read, write, append, or delete). No cooperation is required for users that require only metadata access (i.e. read and write [extended] attributes; owner/group; and the discretionary and system ACL). Since you only have read access and share all access, a subsequent open with read, write, or delete access is only required to share read access at a minimum.